# Spring batch Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode) error

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I use Spring Batch for parse csv file. It works great, when file in resource directory, but doesn't work from another place. I get suck error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): class path resource [c:/data/geodata1.csv]
```

My code

```
spring.datasource:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;MODE=Oracle
server:
  port: 9001
geodata:
  file: c:/data/geodata1.csv

@Value("${geodata.file}")
private String filePath;

@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Person>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource(filePath));
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Person>() {{
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
            setNames(new String[] {"clientId", "longitude", "latitude", });
        }});
        setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
            setTargetType(Person.class);
        }});
    }});
    return reader;
}
```

But this code works good

```
File file = new File(filePath);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found the solution use `org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource;` class instead of `org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;`

Answer (score 10):

use  **PathResource** from **org.springframework.core.io**  , it worked for me

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<CourseCountry> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters[fullPathFileName]}") String pathToFile) {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<CourseCountry>()
      .name("studentItemReader")        
      .resource(new PathResource(pathToFile))
      .lineMapper(lineMapper())
      .linesToSkip(1)
      .build();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had find the same problem and i'd use org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource class like this:
file: c:\data\geodata1.csv
reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(file));

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :** You can use PathResource as follows

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
   new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
                .name("JobName")
                .resource(new PathResource(getReceivedFilePath("Location")))
                .targetType("Targetclass".class)
                .linesToSkip(" count of no of lines to skip")
                .delimited()
                .delimiter(recordSeparator)
                .includedFields(new Integer[] { 0, 1})
                .names(new String[] { "param1 in target class","param2 in target class etc" })
                .build();
}
```

The getReceivedFilePath that u pass to PathResource should be as follows, which takes any file that starts with or ends with etc.

```
 public String getReceivedFilePath(String fileName) {

        File directory = new File(file.location);
        if (directory.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = directory.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.toLowerCase().endsWith("extension.type"));
            for (File file : files) {
                if (FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getName()).startsWith(FilenameUtils.getBaseName(fileName))) {
                    return file.getAbsolutePath();
                }
            }
        }
        return directory.getName();
    }
```

**Solution 2 :** You can use PathResource, but your filename should match the exact path that you supply

Ex:  new PathResource("C:\files\filename.csv")